# Duplicate values in R and Python

Tags: python, r, loops

I just have a quick question here.

I am trying to find if there are duplicate values in a vector in R. For example, given the vector below:

```
numbers <- c(10, 45, 32, 10, 56, 43, 32, 9)
```

I want to create a for-loop nested within a for-loop to find if any values occur more than once (i.e. 10 & 32).

I want to do it with nested for loops, since I want to practice doing this with R.

I have accomplished a working script in Python that can succesfully find duplicate values:

```
numbers = [10, 45, 32, 10, 56, 43, 32, 9]

def similars(ourlist, container):

for i in range(len(ourlist)):

    k = i+1

    for j in range(k, len(ourlist)):

        if ourlist[i]==ourlist[j] and ourlist[i] not in container:

            container.append(ourlist[i])

return container

container1=[]

similars(numbers, container1)

print(container1)
```

The above is the Python code, and it finds the duplicate values 10 & 32 when I print (and excuse the possible indentation errors, the indentations sort of messed up when transporting it to StackOverflow :-) ).

I have some R code below that attempts to do the same:

```
numbers <- c(10, 45, 32, 10, 56, 43, 32, 9)

similars <- function(ourlist, container){

for (i in 1:length(ourlist)){

k <- i+1

for (j in k:length(ourlist)){

if (ourlist[i] == ourlist[j] & !(ourlist[i] %in% container)){

container[i] <- ourlist[i]

}
}
}
return (container)
}



container1 <- c()

similars(numbers, container1)

print(container1)
```

However, I get the following error message when I attempt to run it:

```
Error in if (ourlist[i] == ourlist[j] & !(ourlist[i] %in% container)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls: similars
Execution halted
```

I feel there is a simple answer to it, but grudginly, I do not seem to be able to intuit it. Do any of you know why it says "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" when the same error does not occur in Python, and perhaps also how to fix the error in R?

In advance, thank you.

Best regards

Comment: In `R`, yoou don't need any loop to find the duplicates.  There is `duplicated` function which returns logical vector for duplicates and extract the duplicates with that logical output. `numbers[duplicated(numbers)]
[1] 10 32`

Comment: Regarding the issue in code your outer loop will be till the last element, then you are assigning `k <- i + 1`, which will be outside the index

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply and the duplicated function tip! :-) Hmm, I'm not quite sure what else to do with "k <- i+1", since I need to for setting my length in the subsequent loop. What, practically, would you do to remedy it? :-)

Comment: As you wanted to check the previous elements, may be you can start the loop from 2nd element i.e. `2:length(ourlist)` and then use `i-1` to get the previous element/elements

Comment: *"I want to practice doing this with R"* to me clearly communicates that the OP may or may not want the most efficient but wants to learn how to use `for` loops. I agree that `duplicated` and other functions in R are much better for this, @Mike please confirm that you are knowingly doing things "the hard way" for pedagogic reasons?

Comment: @r2evans Yes I am doing it the hard way for pedagogic reasons :)

Comment: @akrun Thanks for helping me, but I cannot quite make the for-loop work unfortunately :-/

Answer (score 1):

1. Your inner loop is extending beyond the length of `ourlist`. With this example `i` will iterate from 1 to 8 (`length(ourlist)`); on the last iteration when `i` is 1, then you call `k <- i+1`, making it `9`. You then iterate `j` from `k` to `length(ourlist)` which evaluates to `9:8` (a decreasing sequence, length 2).

   The answer, knowing that you want to compare an element with the element(s) after it, is that your `i` must iterate up to but not including `length(ourlist)`. In that way, your `k <- i+1` will never be longer than the length of `ourlist`.

   A literal fix for that:

   ```r
   similars <- function(ourlist, container){
     for (i in 1:(length(ourlist)-1)) {
       k <- i+1
       for (j in k:length(ourlist)){
         if (ourlist[i] == ourlist[j] & !(ourlist[i] %in% container)){
           if (is.na(ourlist[i])) browser()
           container[i] <- ourlist[i]
         }
       }
     }
     return (container)
   }
   similars(numbers, container1)
   # [1] 10 NA 32
   ```

   2. Next issue: why the `NA`? That's because you are assigning to the output at index `i`, not necessarily *"append one element to the output"*. Let's do the append:

   ```r
   similars <- function(ourlist, container){
     for (i in 1:(length(ourlist)-1)) {
       k <- i+1
       for (j in k:length(ourlist)){
         if (ourlist[i] == ourlist[j] & !(ourlist[i] %in% container)){
           if (is.na(ourlist[i])) browser()
           container <- c(container, ourlist[i])
           # container[i] <- ourlist[i]
         }
       }
     }
     return (container)
   }
   similars(numbers, container1)
   # [1] 10 32
   ```
2. (Minor.) Inside an `if` clause, the conditional must always be length-1. Use `&&` instead of `&`.

   ```r
   if (ourlist[i] == ourlist[j] && !(ourlist[i] %in% container)){
   ```

   Why? Primarily for short-circuiting. `&` and `|` are vectorized, which means it accepts something like `c(TRUE,FALSE) | c(FALSE, TRUE)`, and it always iterates all aspects of both sides. `&&` is single only, but it short-circuits such that if the first resolves perfectly then the second will not even attempt to evaluate. Examples:

   ```r
   TRUE || stop("oops")
   # [1] TRUE
   FALSE && stop("oops")
   # [1] FALSE
   TRUE && stop("oops")
   # Error: oops
   ```
3. (Minor.) Passing `container` seems unnecessary here. R passes by-reference, so it is not as if you are pre-allocating memory here. I suggest you remove it from the argument list, and pre-define it in the function.

   ```r
   similars <- function(ourlist) {
     container <- c()
     for (i in 1:(length(ourlist)-1)) {
       k <- i+1
       for (j in k:length(ourlist)){
         if (ourlist[i] == ourlist[j] && !(ourlist[i] %in% container)){
           if (is.na(ourlist[i])) browser()
           container <- c(container, ourlist[i])
           # container[i] <- ourlist[i]
         }
       }
     }
     return (container)
   }
   ```
4. (More minor.) Let's think along the computer-science-y (CS) lines of *"allow 0 or more"*. In this sense, is it "reasonable" to pass an empty vector? If that is given as the argument, then one might expect an empty vector be returned as well. *However* ... `1:length(.)` will not work here. Demo:

   ```r
   vec <- 2:4
   1:length(vec)
   # [1] 1 2 3
   seq_along(vec)
   # [1] 1 2 3
   seq_len(length(vec))
   # [1] 1 2 3

   vec <- c()
   1:length(vec)
   # [1] 1 0             # this is broken
   seq_along(vec)
   # integer(0)
   seq_len(length(vec))
   # integer(0)
   ```

   I suggest you use `seq_len(length(ourlist))` (or `length(.)-1`), making the final version in this answer:

   ```r
   similars <- function(ourlist) {
     container <- c()
     for (i in seq_len(max(0, length(ourlist)-1))) {
       k <- i+1
       for (j in (k-1) + seq_len(max(0, length(ourlist)-(k-1)))) {
         if (ourlist[i] == ourlist[j] && !(ourlist[i] %in% container)){
           if (is.na(ourlist[i])) browser()
           container <- c(container, ourlist[i])
           # container[i] <- ourlist[i]
         }
       }
     }
     return (container)
   }
   similars(numbers)#, container1)
   # [1] 10 32
   similars(c())
   # NULL
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The loop can be a single loop instead of nested - loop over the sequence from the 2nd element to the last (`length`), then `if` the current element `ourlist[i]` is present `%in%` the `seq`uence of previous elements and not (`!`) present in the storage container, concatenate (`c`) with the 'container' with the current element and update by assignment (`<-`)

```
similars <- function(ourlist, container){
  for(i in 2:length(ourlist)) {  
      if(ourlist[i] %in% ourlist[seq(i-1)] & !(ourlist[i] %in% container)) {
         container <- c(container, ourlist[i])      
        }
     }
  
     container   
   }
```

-testing

```
> container1 <- c()
> similars(numbers, container1)
[1] 10 32
```

Here, we don't want to use a nested loop because `%in%` is vectorized and thus save a lot of unnecessary iterations

---

It can be done in a more easier way with `duplicated` in `R`

```
> numbers[duplicated(numbers)]
[1] 10 32
```

---

Regarding why there is an error, it is already specified in the comments `Regarding the issue in code your outer loop will be till the last element, then you are assigning k <- i + 1, which will be outside the index`